# Servlet unable to get hash fragment from URL

Tags: servlets, url-fragment

Hi after redirection from OAuth server, I am unable to get the complete URL in my JAVA Servlet.My URL looks like below -

https://host.vp.com/gui/MainPage.gdi#scope=openid%20profile&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV86sada0ajdasJUUEB343KHFKK

I tried request.getRequestURL() , request.getRequestURL(), request.getPathInfo(), no luck in getting the part of the URL which starts after #, i.e., scope=openid%20profile&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV86sada0ajdasJUUEB343KHFKK, Can someone help me here?

Comment: The _fragment_ part (after the `#`) will _never_ be transmitted to the server; this is part of HTTP.

Comment: then how should I get the values after hash, could you highlight?

Answer (score 0):

Your Query string should start with `?` instead of `#` to be able to read in the Selvlet.